# How to load static files in python django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have tried to modify in the settings.py file to allow loading css files but some of html code still doesn't appear with its style, the run in the terminal the command "python manage.py collectstatic" and it says that files are copied but still doesn't appear its effect.

HERE IS THE MODIFIED LINES IN settings.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: In your templates are you doing `{% load staticfiles %}` and then `{% static path-for-my-css %}`?

Comment: {% load static %}                                                                                           <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">                           yes This is in my template

Comment: Change `load static` to `load staticfiles`.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py provide:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files'),
                   )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', )
STATIC_URL = 'http://example.com/static/'
```

So if static files finders are defined and static_files is declared as source for
static files, whatever you place in

```
/your_root/static_files/
```

will come into

```
/your_root/static
```

after you run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

The mistake with

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

is that you're trying to take from and bring to the same directory, which is the destination directory of all static files collected.

Comment: in this line STATIC_URL = 'http://yourdomain.com/static/' what do you mean by my domain, do you mean the path ?

Comment: It's either your localhost or your server's url which is set through reverse proxy like nginx

Comment: it copies the files in the static folder having on them a lock on every file in the folder and all the css doesn't appear at all

Comment: What it does it takes all static files from your system and yours in particular (if set to be static_files or something else) and brings them into static, which is where Django takes them from.

Comment: Your STATICFILES_DIRS must NOT include static, as static is the destination, not source.

Comment: I put both the "static" folder and "static_files" folder in the project and the files was copied from here to there successfully but still no css in the browser appear

Comment: If your static_files/css/style.css exists and is copied to static, then   {{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css is the location

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= " {% static "static/css/menu.css" %} " >   like this ?

Comment: <script src="/static/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script> should load it if {% load static from staticfiles %}  is at the top.

Comment: problem is that it reads a css file and another one not for ex menu.css is not read while style.css is read

Comment: So make a minor update to menu.css and run ./manage.py collectstatic once again - clean up your cache.

Comment: I even put the code all in style.css but still the menu doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

It is better to set `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')`

If you have a folder called `static` in BASE_DIR, add

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

You may add `static_root/` to `.gitignore` file after you run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

The way I use is:

1. Create a static/name_of_app directory where I store my static files

2.In Html

first load static files {% load static %}

then link to the path

href = " {% static 'name_of_app/fileName ' %} "

Answer (score 0):

You can add these codes in your settings.py in latest django version

> STATIC_URL = '/static/'
>
> MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
>
> STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
>
> VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
>
> STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
>
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')

Comment: This answer is not useful in its current form. The difference between the code in the question and this answer is that the paths are different. This is very unlikely to solve the issue.

Comment: This is exactly the same answer than here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57919044/5468463