# Django unable to load static files

Tags: python, django

Completely new to django.

In my settings.py file, I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

My urls.py has

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index)
]
```

And my views.py has

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Finally, I have the following in my index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'styles/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The HTML file loads like it showed but the styles don't show up. On inspection, it says that the CSS file was not found.

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── static
│   ├── scripts
│   │   └── custom.js
│   └── styles
│       └── custom.css
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to tell Django where to find the static files. It is done by setting the [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) on your **settings.py** module.

Usually we do something like this, using the `BASE_DIR`:

**settings.py**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

---

## Some extra info on static settings:

It is a little bit confusing in the beginning, because Django has three similar configuration:

- `STATIC_URL`
- `STATIC_ROOT`
- `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Basically, the `STATIC_URL` will be used to generate a URL to *serve* your static assets. It could be a relative URL like you had:

```
STATIC_URL='/static/'

{% static 'styles/custom.css' %} => /static/styles/custom.css
```

It could be a full URL:

```
STATIC_URL='https://static.yourdomain.com/'

{% static 'styles/custom.css' %} => https://static.yourdomain.com/styles/custom.css
```

Now, the `STATICFILES_DIRS` is where Django will find your static files. It's usually within the project folder. BUT! This is not from where Django will *serve* your static assets to the client. It's like, *where is the source of your static files*.

That's because Django doesn't really serve this kind of files (**.js**, **.css**, **.jpg**). Well, not by default anyway. You could use a third-party app like [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/).

And that's also why we have the `STATIC_ROOT`, which is to tell Django *where to copy those files from the `STATICFILES_DIRS` so someone else can serve it for me*. This someone else is usually Apache or NGINX.

We only use the `STATIC_ROOT` for deployment.

When we deploy a Django application to a productions server, we usually run the command `python manage.py collectstatic`. And that's where Django make a copy of the files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` to the `STATIC_ROOT`.

But during the development phase you don't really have to care about this much detail, because while `DEBUG=True`, Django will make things easier for you and serve the static files.

Answer (score 0):

Add these in your **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]

VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is settings.py code:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
LOGIN_URL = "account:login"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "public:index"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "public:index"


 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'website.apps.accounts',]
```