# Image is not displaying in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am having problem with displaying image in the Django template.Apart from imagefield other field are showing properly.Please find below template and model.Note that I haven't declared any image field in my model.Any help will be much appreciated.

Model.py

```
class Any(models.Model):
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=10,
                            choices=Status_choices,default='SUCCESS')
    Smoke=models.CharField(max_length=10,
                           choices=Smoke_choices,default='SUCCESS')
    Sanity=models.CharField(max_length=100,
                            choices=Sanity_choices,default='YES')
```

Template:

```
<table class = "table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Tag</th>
              <th>Smoke</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Sanity</th>                 
            </tr>
    </thead>         
{% for result in results %} 
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
        <td>
            {% if result.Status == SUCCESS %}<img src='/static/test/img/release.png' class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="20" height="20"/>                     
            {% elif result.Status == FAILURE %} <img src='/static/test/img/block.png' class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="20" height="20"/>
            {% elif result.Sanity == NO %}<img src='/static/test/img/thumbs-down.png' class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="20" height="20"/>
       {% endif %} </td> 
        <td>{{ result.Smoke }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.Status }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.Sanity }}</td>          
    </tr>
   </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you include the STATICFILES_DIRS part in your settings.py?

Comment: Does tags exist in template? If no, try to replace `SUCCESS` to `"SUCCESS"`

Comment: Many thanks Nikitka! its working now.This is the only change I made rest keep as it is

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `src` like below for **static** images.

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'test/img/release.png' %}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="20" height="20"/>
```

Comment: Now it is showing "Generic placeholder thumbnail" instead of image

Comment: That means you are not referring to correct location.

Comment: put `release.png` inside `static/test/img` directory and check it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax

```
 <img src="{% static 'test/img/release.png' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Python/Django application doesn't follow directory structure to serve its views, and by default Django doesn't serve static files (like css, javascript and images for example), the first thing you have to do is tell Django where it can find your static folder.

It is done by setting the `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your **settings.py** module. Usually we do something like this, using the `BASE_DIR`:

**settings.py**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Then, considering you have your `STATIC_URL` set to `/static/`, you can use the `static` template tags, to render your images properly:

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'test/img/release.png' %}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="20" height="20"/>
```

Basically here we are assuming that `BASE_DIR` is the directory where the **manage.py** file is located. So you would need to create a folder named **static** there, and then place your folders **test/img** etc.

> PS: Usually we place the `{% load static %}` on top of the template,
>   after the `{% extends 'base.html' %}` (if you are extending this
>   template from a base template.)

Handling static assets with Django is not immediately obvious, specially if you are coming from a PHP background for example.

I elaborated a little bit more on [that answer about static files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48776397/1011272), maybe it can be useful for understanding more on how it works.